# Downloading a leaflet/arcgis map as a KML file

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, geolocation, arcgis

I have a .io map that I need to download data 2013-2015 from : https://fogocruz.github.io/mapafc/

I'd like to download such data in a way that I could plot it in R, so that I could then cross it with some latitude/longitude data that I have, using the SF package. I managed to download the .kml of the entire state of Rio, but I couldnt download the data of the marked areas in this website.,

I have tried to scrape the index.html from their github (https://github.com/fogocruz/mapafc/blob/main/index.html), unsuccesfully.

Is there any way for me to download the data in there from 2013-2015 as, preferrably, a KML? So that I could plot points over the map and cross-check them.

```
html_in_path <- "C:/Users/username/Downloads/index.html"
html_lines <- readLines(html_in_path)
char_counts <- sapply(X=html_lines, FUN=nchar, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
GeoData <- html_lines[23]
start_string_remove <- '<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-d7e42020b87f95ae6d45">'
GeoData1 <- gsub(start_string_remove, '', GeoData)
GeoData1 <- gsub("</script>", "", GeoData1)
a1 <- toJSON(GeoData1)
```

essentially this is how far i've come - i've been told that I need to clean  GeoData now - tried using gsub() but haven't got it to work; then to export it as a GeoJSON

Comment: How did you fail to scrape the data? It is all in the index file, as JSON data inside a <script> tag. You could also try adding an issue to the site asking nicely for the source data.

Comment: I have been unsucessfully trying to get the data, using rvest, xml2 and such, but I dont find any examples of how to extract the data that works. I am very new to data scraping, and couldn't find any solutions for it.

Comment: The data in the script tag is so large it looks like it breaks `rvest` - maybe there's some buffer size limit or setting I've not found. But python tools - BeautifulSoup, json - read it fine. The resulting JSON data needs picking apart and reconstituting as a spatial object (maybe geoJSON) for conversion to KML. Let me know if you still need this doing since it may take some time...

Comment: Still do. I've managed so far to put the data in R, but cannot parse it at all. How did you manage to get it done using python? I know very little python and PyCharm weirds out in my pc but I can give it a try haha

Comment: If you edit your question to show how far you've got with R that would be very useful.

Comment: I haven't gotten really far; basically managed to get the entire <script> part into R as a "large character " object - I am trying to clean it out by gsub() to then try to parse it with rvest. However, I still get "trailing garbage" when trying to parse.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to an old anwser of yours (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130359/import-data-from-a-leaflet-map-as-an-sf-object-in-r)

I think its the same data to some extent even, mine is just from a more complete (and messier) source I guess. Its the same data in the sense that its from the same place, about the same information ; Unfortunately it does not have the same characteristics as the data I need for my study :(

Comment: I've reported a possible bug with rvest on long lines: https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/399